# OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag not found while writing video from images

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to write a video using images in `Python` and on `Ubuntu 14.04` and getting the following error:

> OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0xffffffff/'����' is not found (format 'mp4 / MP4
>   (MPEG-4 Part 14)')'

The code I'm using is listed below.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("image.png")
height , width , layers =  img.shape
video = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4',-1,1,(width,height))
video.write(img)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

Comment: did you solve this problem ?

Comment: Also wondering if you have found a solution to this